# Magento 2 new customer account form not working

Tags: magento2

Guests are not able to create new account.

After they filling the form and pressing on create an account nothing is happening, no account created and no error is showing.

Answer (score 14):

I have same issue after upgrade from magento 2.1.8 to 2.1.9. I am using custom theme.

I have added form key code in file after `<form>` tag at line 21. `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml`

Code

```
<?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
```

Comment: Why does the registration work in the default Magento template? There is no formkey there either.

Comment: There is at least in Magento 2.1.14 Check /vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml

Answer (score 4):

### Those developing locally encountering this issue:

Make sure that you are not using `localhost` as your domain name.

Using Xdebug, I determined that the form key output to `/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml` (or any form for that matter) via `$block->getBlockHtml('formkey');` was not the same that was ultimately rendered in the HTML `form_key` hidden input element.

I determined that the problem stems from the `_create` function in  `/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/view/frontend/web/js/page-cache.js`.

Within this function, `$.mage.cookies.get('form_key');` returns `null` when using localhost, hence a new random key is generated and overwrites the form key value provided by the block output mentioned above.

#### Solution:

Using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` (or, of course mapping any other desired domain name to `127.0.0.1`) resolves this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I could say that in your custom `register.phtml` template where the registration form is, that there is not form key in the form that you submit. Add after the form element the following code

```
<?php /* @noEscape */ echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

Don't forget afterwards to clear cache.

Answer (score 2):

You must be using chrome browser.Try in other browser.

Change your localhost address as a site name(localhost.com) in (/etc/hosts file) which make it look secure to a browser.
Use same address in base url option in **Stores->Web->Base URLs**

Comment: not working on all browsers
why to use localhost my site is live

Comment: 1. check permissons of root directory
2. configure server file and hosts file
3. restart server

Comment: DId you update magento to another version lately?

Answer (score 0):

please provide the 'ipaddress' instead of 'localhost'(url) in core_config_data table in phpmyadmin